# Set Value doesn't save values when I click on Submit button

Tags: javascript, settext, rpa

I have a page where I'm setting the value of text boxes using document.getElementById, but when I'm clicked on "Guardar" button the values doesn't saves, how can I solve?

This is the code:

```
document.getElementById("Crm_CustomModule3_COBJ3CF82_LInput").value = "01/10/2022"
```

This is the text field that I set (vigencia hasta):

[image]

And this is the page after y clicked on "Guardar" button

[image]

The value doesn't saves.

Comment: Please show us the full code which tries to save the value. We cannot evaluate without the full code.

Comment: mmmm I'm only set value using document.getElementById, save action I'm do with a "Guardar" button.

Comment: So what I see on that code is that you only want to set the value of an element called `Crm_CustomModule3_COBJ3CF82_LInput`. This won't save anything, it just will display another value in the input field.

Comment: So, how can I save the value?

Comment: Where do you want it to be saved? Do you have the suiting backend?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to trigger the onChange or onInput listener to save your input. Depends on the site structure.
Something like:

```
element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change',{'bubbles':true}))
```

or

```
element.dispatchEvent(new Event('input',{'bubbles':true}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you have input textbox id as Crm_CustomModule3_COBJ3CF82_LInput

Comment: Yes, I'm using this: document.getElementById("Crm_CustomModule3_COBJ3CF82_LInput").value = "01/10/2022"